# Can we use a pre trained Encoder (BERT, XLM ) with a Decoder (GPT, Transformer-XL) to build a Chatbot instead of Language Translation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, deep-neural-networks, bert

I was wondering if the `BERT` or `T5` models can do the task of generating sentences in English. Most of the models I have mentioned are trained to translate from English to German or French. Is it possible that I can use the output of `BERT` as an input to my Decoder? My theory is that when I already have the trained `Embeddings`, I do not need to train the Encoder part. I can just add the outputs of sentences to the decoder to generate the sentences.

In place of finding the loss value from the translated version, Can I compute loss on the reply of a sentence?

Can someone point me toward a tutorial where I can use the `BERT` output for the decoder part? I have a data of conversation with me. I want to build a `Chatbot` from that data.

I have already implemented `LSTM` based `Sequence2sequence` model but it is not providing me satisfactory answer.

After some research, 2 such models are there as `T5` and `BART` which are based on the same idea.

If possible, can someone tell me how can I use `BART` or `T5` to make a conversational bot?

Answer (score 1):

=> I don't have more ideas about **BART** and **T5** Right now. but I had created a chatbot Based on **GPT-2** Model-based on [Microsoft DialoGPT](https://github.com/microsoft/DialoGPT). Which is fine-tuned on millions of parameters of Reddit. you can fine-tune on your own data using DialoGPT. I had not found a public decoding method. So, We tried to generate diverse responses using simple **nucleus sampling** at each time step. So, We used **greedy nucleus sampling multiple times** in parallel to generate multiple candidates responses. We generated 30 such responses for each turn and also used the last 3 turn conversation history as extra context for generator. So, We can generate responses related to the current Context of Conversation.

We used Code reference from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-_KjlAV3J1IVDw_9KogjKDCzgFY7Jp7E#scrollTo=RZd4iXX5SqKC). you need to implement greedy nucleus sampling multiple on this code.

=>Now To Choose the best-matched response from response generated I created a Reranker.I used two sub-component.

=>Component one Counts **Cosine similarity** between Response and Query using [sentence Encoder](https://github.com/PolyAI-LDN/polyai-models/blob/master/encoder_client.py).

=>In Component Two we **cross-entropy error** for generating original query from the response.For that I used reverse-generator of [DialogueGPT](https://github.com/microsoft/DialoGPT).

We Combined Score of Both Component as `Score=norm(comp1Score)+norm(1-comp2Loss)`. Using this score you can find best response.

For Tutorial My Favourite [Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) they have **BERT,GPT, GPT-2, XLNET,etc...**
and Second Favourite [Facebook ParlAI](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI), 
try [Blender Model](https://parl.ai/projects/recipes/) also.

Comment: But can we use outputs of `BERT` as the the  `K`' and `'V` values to an attention Decoder in the simplest terms possible to minimize the `binary cross entropy`?

Comment: @HirenNamera Can you please use `this` style only for code? You can and should use _this_ or **this** style if you need to emphasize something.

Comment: I think it is possible to minimize **binary cross entropy**. Why not you try using huggingface's `pretrainedencoderdecoder` module. Using **bert-base-uncased** as encoder and **gpt-2 large** as a decoder.